# Error 500.19 - Deploy Dot net core api project in IIS

Tags: .net-core

I am working with dot net core 2.1.I am trying to deploy dot net core api application in iis but got following error.
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

I tried to resolve it by installing following hosting bundles but not succeeded.
aspnetcore-runtime-2.2.8-win-x64
dotnet-runtime-2.1.17-win-x64
dotnet-runtime-2.2.8-win-x64

When i click on module section in IIS i got following error.
There was an error while performing this operation.
Filename:\D:\Myproject\Web.config

Answer (score 0):

First issue is related to module section which i resolved by changing module element into web.config file from "AspNetCoreModule" to "AspNetCoreModuleV2".

```
 <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

then i face another issue on hosted env. which is related to .net framwork incompatibility.
For above issue i publish my application in self contained mode and issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Under IIS  open IIS Manager

1. Click Applications Pools
2. select Application Pool you are using
3. click on Advanced Setting on Right Panel of IIS and
4. Change Identity to **LocalSystem**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhRjp.png)